# Stuck notification on LG 's Phone app "new voice mail"

Tags: notifications, lg, voicemail

My phone's an LG G4 on Android 6. I've received a new vocal message which I've read already. The notification won't go away.

I can't force close the app as it's a system app ( "Phone" )
I can't disable notifications on this app for the same reason.

When I reboot the phone, the notification show up again...

Any idea would be appreciated. Thx

Comment: Have you tried clearing the data/cache of *Phone*?

Comment: Hey thank you! there was no data in Phone app's cache but some storage was used. The notification is removed once storage  cleared! I'll tell you if the notification pops out again ^^